# Extract paired lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I've got a txt file like this. There are paired lines `email-password` and `email-hash`.

```
EMAIL:user1@site.com
PASSWORD:pass1
EMAIL:user2@site.com
PASSWORD:pass2
EMAIL:user3@site.com
PASSWORD:pass3
EMAIL:user4@site.com
HASH:qwerty123
EMAIL:user5@site.com
HASH:somehash
EMAIL:user6@site.com
PASSWORD:pass6
```

I try to extract only `email-password` lines excluding `email-hash` lines.
The command isn't working properly in my case `sed -e 's/.*EMAIL://' -e 's/.*PASSWORD://' -e "/\b\HASH\b/d" test.txt`

Expect the output:

```
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6
```

Comment: Can a `:` exist in any of the fields?

Answer (score 10):

```
sed -n 'N;s/^EMAIL://;s/PASSWORD://p' file
```

- `N` append next line to pattern space,
- `s/^EMAIL://` substitute `EMAIL:` with nothing,
- `s/PASSWORD://p` substitute `PASSWORD:` with nothing and **only print if the substitution was successful**.

Tested on sample input. Assumption: 1st line is `EMAIL:`, 2nd is `PASSWORD:` or `HASH:`, and repeat.

---

As a bonus, if there may be blank lines, it is better to use Awk,

```
awk -F ':' '/^PASSWORD:/{print line;print $2}/^EMAIL:/{line=$2}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another couple of variations:

```bsh
paste -d :  - - < myfile | awk -F: '$3 == "PASSWORD" {print $2; print $4}'
```

```bsh
tac myfile | awk -F: '$1 == "PASSWORD" {print $2; getline; print $2}' | tac
```

Answer (score 4):

**pbm identification**
As you know sed is a line oriented stream editor, so when the decision to print or not to print lies in another line like in this your case, we need to orchestrate a state machine, and they will need flip flops or variables in this case.

Essentially we need to hold back printing till we see the correct state transition. Like in this case, when we transition from state (email line) -> state(passwd line) only.

Using `GNU sed` in extended regex mode `-E`, which makes reading the sed code easier and writing it less prone to backslashitis.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    /^PASSWORD:/!{h;d;}
    x;G;s/(^|\n)[^:]*:/\1/g
' test.txt
```

Basic idea is to save the line which isn't a password line in the hold register so that when we actually get to the password line we can use it.

Using `GNU awk` we essentially code the above sed functionality in awk with the awk variable e serving as the hold register.

```
$ awk -F: '
    /^PASSWORD:/&&
    ($0=e RS $2)"";{e=$2}
' test.txt
```

Using `GNU grep` we use the before option `-B` to list one line before the password line then remove the dash line generated by grep and assume nobody uses that as a password.

```
$ < test.txt \
  grep -B1 '^PASSWORD:' |
  grep -Fxve -- | cut -d: -f2-
```

`perl` can be used as shown when we pick the next line and then checks made.

```
$ perl -ne '
    /^EMAIL:/ && ($_ .= <>);
    /\nPASSWORD:/ && print(s/^[^:]+://mgr);
' tes.txt
```

**bash builtins**

```
while IFS=: read -r a p; do
  case $a in
    'PASSWORD') printf '%s\n' "$e" "$p" ;;
    *) e=$p ;;
  esac
done < test.txt
```

Comment: +1: so many ways ... I particularly like the `bash` built-in variation.

Comment: a portable way to get rid of lines starting with "--" in them could be : `grep -v "^--"`

Comment: Note that the *bash builtins* variant (which btw has nothing bash-specific in it) doesn't work properly if the email address or password ends in a `:` character (and contains no other `:` character). I can't help but to also refer to [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` to pull out the lines that we're interested in, and then `cut` to remove the `PASSWORD:` and `EMAIL:` strings from the start of each line:

```
$ sed -n 'N; /\nPASSWORD:/p' file | cut -d : -f 2-
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6
```

Using `cut` here helps keep the `sed` expression, and therefore the whole command, simple.

Answer (score 2):

If the data you want printed can't contain any `:`s:

```
$ awk -F':' '$1=="PASSWORD"{print prev ORS $2} {prev=$2}' file
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6
```

or if it can then either of these would work, just your preference:

```
$ awk '{prev=curr; curr=$0; sub(/[^:]+:/,"",curr)} /^PASSWORD:/{print prev ORS curr}' file
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6

$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]+:/,"")} tag=="PASSWORD"{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}' file
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6

$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]+:/,""); prev=curr; curr=$0} tag=="PASSWORD"{print prev ORS curr}' file
user1@site.com
pass1
user2@site.com
pass2
user3@site.com
pass3
user6@site.com
pass6
```

Answer (score 2):

If that file is always in that format with `EMAIL` at the start of every other line:

```
sed -n 'N;s/^EMAIL:\(.*\n\)PASSWORD:/\1/p'
```

should do it. Or, to be on the safe side, look for `EMAIL:` as the start of the record:

```
sed -n '/^EMAIL:/{N;s/^EMAIL:\(.*\n\)PASSWORD:/\1/p;}'
```

You could also use `pcregrep` with its multiline mode:

```
pcregrep -M -o1 -o2 --om-separator=$'\n' '^EMAIL:(.*)\nPASSWORD:(.*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "N;s/\n/ /g" filename| awk -F ":" '/PASSWORD/{gsub("PASSWORD","",$2);print $2"\n"$3  }'


output

user1@site.com 
pass1
user2@site.com 
pass2
user3@site.com 
pass3
user6@site.com 
pass6
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=[]
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    m.append(i.strip())

for j in range(0,len(m),2):
    if "PASSWORD" in m[j+1]:
        print m[j].split(":")[-1]
        print m[j+1].split(":")[-1]
```