# Extracting salt:hash from a text file

Tags: hashsum

Currently, I don't seem to be able to find a script or guide online to find out how to extract the `hash:salt` into a text file.

For example

```
user,7,17,email,alis,,,b8e44d9a607d0c547294b24eac45399:tEleOY91IV7IKVqzqlp21sbmeuEFpU68,0,252dc07d557dfd2185603a8c2fe4cd94,2019-03-28 19:15:47.0
```

I came across [Extract paired lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607253/extract-paired-lines) which kind of helped but didn't achieve what I was looking for.

I am trying to extract the `b8e44d9a607d0c547294b24eac45399:tEleOY91IV7IKVqzqlp21sbmeuEFpU68` section.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data appears to be comma-separated, with the desired text in the 8th field.  If the text you want is always going to be in the 8th field, you can use `awk -F, '{print $8}'`.  For example:

```
echo "user,7,17,email,alis,,,b8e44d9a607d0c547294b24eac45399:tEleOY91IV7IKVqzqlp21sbmeuEFpU68,0,252dc07d557dfd2185603a8c2fe4cd94,2019-03-28 19:15:47.0" | awk -F, '{print $8}'
b8e44d9a607d0c547294b24eac45399:tEleOY91IV7IKVqzqlp21sbmeuEFpU68
```

Comment: Or just `cut -d , -f 8`.